# In angularJS, insert information into function property

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, factory

This is the function I made:

```
    var _loadNieuws =
    function (url) {
        switch (url) {
        case 'example1':
            _nieuws = EXAMPLE1_NIEUWS;
            break;
        case 'example2':
            _nieuws = EXAMPLE2_NIEUWS;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to give the url a value using my controller, this is how far I came: `NieuwsService.loadNieuws.url = 'example1';`

But then I get this error:
"Cannot set property 'url' of undefined".

This is my whole factory:

```
    App.factory('NieuwsService', ['EXAMPLE1_NIEUWS', 'EXAMPLE2_NIEUWS', function (EXAMPLE1_NIEUWS, EXAMPLE2_NIEUWS) {
    var nieuwsService = {};

    var _nieuws = [];

    var _loadNieuws =
    function (url) {
        switch (url) {
        case 'example1':
            _nieuws = EXAMPLE1_NIEUWS;
            break;
        case 'example2':
            _nieuws = EXAMPLE2_NIEUWS;
            break;
        }
    }

    nieuwsService.loadNiews = _loadNieuws;
    nieuwsService.nieuws = _nieuws;

    return nieuwsService;

}]);
```

So my question is how do I give the property url in the function a value using my controller ?

Comment: there is no variable named NieuwsService  or loadNieuws...
So you got to define a proper object before setting url field

Comment: try something like :   $scope.url = "/some/path"; and then call the function in controller like this : NieuwsService.loadNiews(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked fine for me:

```
var url = 'example1';

$scope.url = angular.copy(NieuwsService.loadNieuws(url));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this in your controller :

```
$scope.url = NieuwsService.loadNieuws('example1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the question?

If you want to pass variable into the function put it as a parameter in function:

```
<div ng-click="_loadNieuws(loadNieuws.url)">Click here</div>
```

and your js-code will work fine